# how to select values from multiple columns based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which has information about people with balance in their different accounts. It looks something like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John', 'Jacob', 'Mary', 'Sue', 'Harry', 'Clara'],
                   'accnt_1':[2, np.nan, 13, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'accnt_2':[32, np.nan, 12, 21, 32, np.nan],
                   'accnt_3':[11,21,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan]})
df
```

[image]

I want to get balance for each person as if accnt_1 is not empty that is the balance of that person. If accnt_1 is empty and accnt_2 is not, number in accnt_2 is the balance. If both accnt_1 and accnt_2 are empty, whatever is in accnt_3 is the balance.
In the end the output should look like

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John', 'Jacob', 'Mary', 'Sue', 'Harry', 'Clara'],
                  'balance':[2, 21, 13, 21, 32, np.nan]})
out_df
```

[image]

I will always know the priority of columns. I can write a simple function and apply on this dataframe. But I was thinking is there a better and faster way to do using pandas/numpy?

Answer (score 0):

If balanced means first not missing values after `name` you can convert `name` to index, then back filling missing values and select first column by position:

```
df = df.set_index('name').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].rename('balance').reset_index()
print (df)
    name  balance
0   John      2.0
1  Jacob     21.0
2   Mary     13.0
3    Sue     21.0
4  Harry     32.0
5  Clara      NaN
```

If need specify columns names in order by list:

```
cols = ['accnt_1','accnt_2','accnt_3']
df = df.set_index('name')[cols].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].rename('balance').reset_index()
```

Or if need filter only `accnt` columns use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df = df.set_index('name').filter(like='accnt').bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].rename('balance').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chain `fillna` methods onto each other to achieve your desired result. The chaining can be read in plain english closely to: "take the values in accnt_1, fill the missing values in accnt_1 with values from accnt_2. Then if there are still remaining NaN after this, fill those missing values with the values from accnt_3"

```
>>> df["balance"] = df["accnt_1"].fillna(df["accnt_2"]).fillna(df["accnt_3"])
>>> df[["name", "balance"]]
    name  balance
0  John   2.0    
1  Jacob  21.0   
2  Mary   13.0   
3  Sue    21.0   
4  Harry  32.0   
5  Clara  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['balance']=df.name.map(df.set_index('name').stack().groupby('name').first())



   name  accnt_1  accnt_2  accnt_3  balance
0   John      2.0     32.0     11.0      2.0
1  Jacob      NaN      NaN     21.0     21.0
2   Mary     13.0     12.0      NaN     13.0
3    Sue      NaN     21.0      NaN     21.0
4  Harry      NaN     32.0      2.0     32.0
5  Clara      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

**How it works**

```
#setting name as index gives you an opportunity to get it as a column name when you unstack

df.set_index('name').stack().groupby('name').first()

name          
John   accnt_1     2.0
       accnt_2    32.0
       accnt_3    11.0
Jacob  accnt_3    21.0
Mary   accnt_1    13.0
       accnt_2    12.0
Sue    accnt_2    21.0
Harry  accnt_2    32.0
       accnt_3     2.0
dtype: float64

#Chaining .first() gets you the first index value that is non NaN because when you stack NaN is dropped

df.set_index('name').stack().groupby('name').first()

#.map() allows you to map output above to the original dataframe

df.name.map(df.set_index('name').stack().groupby('name').first())

0     2.0
1    21.0
2    13.0
3    21.0
4    32.0
5     NaN
```